# How to set the color of line segments

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following MWE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = [8, 5, 7, 10, 3, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6]
plt.plot(range(len(l)), l, marker=".", markersize=20)
```

[image]

I would like the line segments to be colored according to the contents of `l`. So the first segment would be color `8`, the second color `5` etc.  I don't mind too much which color pallete these colors are chosen from as long as the colors are clearly distinct.

How can you do that?

Comment: Also consider this: `pairs = list(zip(l[:-1], l[1:]))`, `for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):`
`plt.plot([i, i+1], pair, c=f'C{l[i]}', marker=".", markersize=20)`

Comment: @K.Cl How is C defined?

Comment: `'C0'`, `'C1'`, ..., '`Cn`' are shorthands for the n-th color of the current color cycle you have active.